# actionSupport Rerender in a wrapper class

Tags: actionsupport, wrapper-class

I want a value from one input field to be copied into all pageBlock fields. I could insert records with the value, but then user wouldn't be able to change individual values in the pageBlock.

Current code is:

```
      <apex:form >  
<apex:inputtext value="{!newQuoteValue}" required="true">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="newQuotesBlock"/>
        </apex:inputText>     
        <apex:pageblock id="newQuotesBlock" >
          <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapperObj}" var="Rec">
              <apex:column headerValue="£/year"  >
              <apex:inputtext value="{!Rec.Standing}" required="true"/>
             </apex:column>
```

Apex:

```
Public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList {get;set;}
public long newQuoteValue {get;set;}
Public Class WrapperClassEx{
     Public WrapperClassEx(sobject accRec, string meterNameMethodVar, string meterAQ, string meterIDs, long massStanding ){
        elecObj = accRec;
        meterName = meterNameMethodVar;
        AQ=meterAQ;
        meterID=meterIDs;
        standing=massStanding;
     }
   }
Public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj(){
List<electricity_meter__c> MeterList = [Select id,name,AQ__c,meter_details__c from electricity_meter__c where (Linked_Monitor_Line__c =: lineId)]; 
      WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();
      for(electricity_meter__c met: MeterList){
        String meterNameInner = String.valueOf( met.get('Name') );
        String meterAQ = String.valueOf( met.get('AQ__c') );
        String meterID = String.valueOf( met.get('meter_details__c') );  
        long massStanding = newQuoteValue;
        WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(met,meterNameInner,meterAQ,meterID,massStanding )); 
      } 
      return WrapperList;
   }
```

I am guessing that getwrapperObj is not being updated from onChange event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is easiest done using Javascript (specifically using the jQuery library) instead of a Controller Action Method.

To do this, let's first create a Javascript function called `copyInput`.  This function takes in the HTML-element calling the method as its input (ex. copyInput(this);).  Then it copies the input's value to the input of all inputs with the class `inputToCopyTo`.  This is done via

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"/>
<!-- Note:  You should probably download and save the jQuery version you use as
            Static Resource and then use {!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryResourceName)}
            instead of the url   --> 
<script>
    var j$=jQuery.noConflict();

    function copyInput(thar){
        var inputValue=j$(thar).val();
        // set the inputValue to all inputs with the class "inputToCopyTo"
        j$('.inputToCopyTo').val(inputValue);
    }
</script>
```

Then, let's trigger the function on the `onkeyup` event on the master-input. (Try using the `onchange` event too to see the difference.  I generally prefer the feel onkeyup, but that's just me.)

Finally, let's add the class `inputToCopyTo` to the pabeBlockTable's inputs so those inputs get whoever is using the `copyInput` function we made.

Putting this all together:

```
<apex:form >  
    <apex:inputtext value="{!newQuoteValue}" required="true" onkeyup="copyInput(this);"> <!-- Changed by OP as this was bugging -->
    </apex:inputText>     
    <apex:pageBlock id="newQuotesBlock" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperObj}" var="Rec">
            <apex:column headerValue="£/year"  >
                <apex:inputtext value="{!Rec.Standing}" required="true" styleClass="inputToCopyTo"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<apex:includeScript value="https://http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"/>
<!-- Note:  You should probably download and save the jQuery version you use as
            Static Resource and then use {!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryResourceName)}
            instead of the url   -->
<script>
    var j$=jQuery.noConflict();

    function copyInput(thar){
        var inputValue=j$(thar).val();
        // set the inputValue to all inputs with the class "inputToCopyTo"
        j$('.inputToCopyTo').val(inputValue);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However I changed from onkeydown to onkeyup, as it was only changing after second key press. Any ideas for picklists?

Comment: Picklists worked using the same way as inputfields.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you have missed providing an action to `action:support` it should be something like:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!someControllerMethod}" rerender="newQuotesBlock"/>
```

Reference: [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm)

Comment: Good point, although using getwrapperObj() method wouldn't update them. I assume I need to write a new method that updates wrapperObj ?

Comment: @dzh yes, a new method !